# Output from TCL to running terminal

Tags: cygwin, tcl, codewarrior

Basically i'm connecting to a cygwin terminal on another computer and running a program(CodeWarrior) that has TCL support. Running tcl commands inside the program is not a problem.
 What i am trying is to redirect output (from puts for example) in tcl to my running cygwin console.

Comment: Is that a _real_ terminal (virtual or physical)? Is it the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the terminal is the current one, you can do this:

```
set terminal [open /dev/tty]

puts $terminal "Hi there!"
```

You might make the terminal handle a global one and never close it (until the program exits).

---

Other terminals can be written to — provided you have permission — by just opening the correct device. Or you can open a file descriptor if you can find it in `/proc`, though that's a little bit of a black art in itself.

Comment: What i'm trying is from a cygwin terminal i run a batch containing: CALL cwide.exe -data "..workspace" -Dcw.script"..script.tcl" . Inside that script i must write a way to communicate with my terminal. If i pwd i get "C:\..workspace" so how do i open a pipeline to my ongoing terminal, all this from inside my Codewarrior